# Custom function "breaks" when re-used on same page

Tags: javascript, oop, function, multiple-instances

I thought I could make my own dynamic slideshow script.

```
function slider( container )
{
    var time = 1200;
    var width = 1000;
    var container = document.getElementById(container);
    var name = container.childNodes[1].className;
    var content = document.getElementsByClassName(name);

    var num = ( content.length * width );

    next = function()
    {           
        var px = container.style.marginLeft;
        var diff = Math.abs( px.replace( 'px', '' ) );
        var shifted = ( diff ) ? ( diff / width ) : '0';

        shifted++;

        if ( shifted == content.length )
        {
            shifted = 0;

            shift();
        }

        container.style.marginLeft = ( shifted == content.length ) ? '0' : '-' + ( shifted * width ) + 'px';
    }

    shift = function()
    {   
        for ( var i = 0; i < content.length; i++ )
        {
            var delay = ( ( i + 1 ) * time );

            setTimeout( next, delay );
        }
    }

    container.style.width = num + 'px';

    shift();
}
```

Works fine with all other slideshow containers. The slide is always changed by the internal function

> function next()

This function determines what slide is next and when the slides are at the end to reset them using another internal function

> function shift()

It's interchangeable using different vars for different DIV containers but when I try to run multiple instances, like below

> slider( 'element' );
>   slider( 'element2' );

At first it runs the code and cycles through the slides for all elements, but only the FIRST instance will reset properly and continue "sliding" from start to end, over and over. After the duplicate instances are shift()'d, the required next() is not called for the duplicates.

Moving slider() outside of master class altogether and calling it from the page is the same result.

Fiddle away, since it's probably a one-line fix.

http://jsfiddle.net/6LeUR/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're going to need to show your actual code - we can't tell what's wrong without seeing it. (And it never hurts to supply a demo at [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net).)

Comment: Thanks! I have since shown the code used. Edit: Very neat and useful site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var content = document.getElementsByClassName(name);
```

…will find all elements with that class on the entire page, not simply within that slider. Try changing it to:

```
var content = container.getElementsByClassName(name);
```

Additionally, add `var` before `next =` and `shift =`. **[Try it.](http://jsfiddle.net/6LeUR/1/)**

Comment: Thank you very much, I like to think I'll catch that next time. Keep teaching, we're never done learning.